# Android delete layout from layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the next problem. Server send me a response and depends from this response my screen have or does not have some layout.For example :if server return 0, I need to remove my LinearLayout but_status_group. I removed layout, but on this place I have a free space, how can I up to the top layouts and view, that stayed before but_status_group?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/operation_additional_data">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/status"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/but_status_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_below="@id/status_description"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but_confirm"
            android:text="@string/confirm_but"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but_generate_code"
            android:text="@string/take_new_code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/but_status_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/reference"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/operation_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/operation_creation_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/operation_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operation_details_header"
        android:text="@string/payment_details_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/operation_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operation_details"
        android:layout_below="@id/operation_details_header"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the layout using

```
myLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

you will get that blank space.

Remove it using

```
myLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

So that space will be covered by next layout. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

remove the parent layout Linear Layout to Relative layout and maintain dependency for it.

Answer (score 0):

**My Experience**:I think It is better if you make different layout file for different type of view as It will be lot easier to maintain the code.If requirement varies your code may be broke down.It is lot easier to change the code when requirement changes.